# three body collision detection issue in xcode

Tags: swift, collision-detection, collision

I'm having an issue with the rare occurrence when three bodies collide at once and crash my app.  The collision detection between body1 and body2 or body1 and body3 is working great (body2 and body3 collision doesn't matter and can pass right through each other) as long as the three bodies don't happen to collide at once.  When that happens I get these errors:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

and

> thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0

Any help is much appreciated. Related code is below.

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody!
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody!
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Enemy != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Star != 0)) {
        starDidCollideWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, enemy: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Enemy != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Flyer != 0)) {
        flyerDidCollideWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, enemy: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
```

Maybe there's a way to add a third body? Or some way of detecting 2 cases of a body contacting a case of another body?

Playing around with more I learned the problem is eliminated if I don't removeFromParent one of the colliding objects.  This isn't ideal for the game though so I'd hopefully be able to eliminate this crash and still remove all colliding objects. Maybe there's just a remove all involved from parent?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what is happening is this.

The runtime error that you are seeing occurs when you force unwrap an optional that holds nil. And, in your snippet, firstBody and secondBody are forced unwrapped by definition (because of the '!' on their type annotation).

I'm assuming that starDidCollideWithEnemy removes either the firstBody or the secondBody from the scene. Or otherwise nils them out.

Then, in the case of a double collision, the next if block gets evaluated. But either firstBody or secondBody is already nil - so the whole thing blows up.

Maybe the simplest thing would be to evaluate the second test inside an else block of the first.

```
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Enemy != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Star != 0)) {
        starDidCollideWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, enemy: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }

    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Enemy != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Flyer != 0)) {
        flyerDidCollideWithEnemy(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, enemy: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ncke, I tried adding the else but still get the crash when all three bodies collide at once.  You were correct in that starDidCollideWithEnemy removes the 2 colliding bodies involved, so does flyerDidCollideWithEnemy.  Maybe there's a way to test all 3 body collision and if so remove all bodies involved in the collision?